# React portal popup window variable

Tags: javascript, reactjs, popup

I'm currently trying to create a PopUp with `ReactDOM.createPortal`.
I've already gone through https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/12355
and used the following code

```
class Window extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = { win: null, el: null };
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    let win = window.open('', '', 'width=600,height=400');
    win.document.title = 'A React portal window';
    let el = document.createElement('div');
    win.document.body.appendChild(el);
    this.setState({ win, el });
  }

  componentWillUnmount() {
    this.state.win.close();
  }

  render() {
    const { el } = this.state;
    if (!el) {
      return null;
    }
    return ReactDOM.createPortal(this.props.children, el);
  }
}
```

The main problem is that `this.props.children` can contain components that register event handlers as

[image]

and `windows` variable still refers to the primary window, and not the recently opened PopUp.

https://codepen.io/ggcatu/pen/OJJGxYW?editors=0010
I would like to calculate the popUp X & Y.
I DON'T want to pass `this.state.win` into the new children, as they can contain library components, that are just directly calling `window.screenX`

Any know workarounds?

Comment: I got the same issue, did you get a solution on this? @gabriel

Comment: I had this issue before, as a workaround I ditched using portals completely. Depending on how your application is designed this could be relatively easy. Basically instead of using a portal I just set up a new route/page in my application and requested a window to be open at that page. You could share state via window message passing or query parameters.

Answer (score 0):

You could try wrapping the children:

```
return ReactDOM.createPortal(
<div id='portal'>{this.props.children}</div>, el);
```

Style it as needed and then add an event listener from the child component?

```
const portal = document.getElementById('portal');
portal.addEventListener(etc)
```

Answer (score 0):

I made a medium post of this thing last year, you don't need portals, portals works with dom elements.
https://enetoolveda.medium.com/open-a-popup-window-react-db81c8c180e5

here the code https://codesandbox.io/s/keen-sea-2xow0?file=/src/home.js

Let's assume I create a CRA project

my App.js looks like this

```js
import React from 'react';
import { BrowserRouter, Redirect, Route, Switch } from "react-router-dom";
import './App.css';
import { Home } from "./Home";
import { Son } from "./Son";

function App() {

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <BrowserRouter>
      <Switch>
        <Route exact path="/son" component={Son}/>
        <Route exact path="/" component={Home}/>
        <Redirect from="*" to="/" />
      </Switch>
      </BrowserRouter>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

we need to components the actual popup and the container component.

the secret begin this is that the popup does not
know it is an external window. it needs to be agnostic about that.

create the window opener

```
import React, { useEffect } from "react";

let browser = window.self;
let popup;
let timer;

// This function is what the name says.
// it checks whether the popup still open or not
function watcher() {
  // if popup is null then let's clean the intervals.
  if (popup === null) {
    clearInterval(timer);
    timer = undefined;
    // if popup is not null and it is not closed, then let's set the focus on it... maybe...
  } else if (popup !== null && !popup.closed) {
    popup.focus();
    // if popup is closed, then let's clean errthing.
  } else if (popup !== null && popup.closed) {
    clearInterval(timer);
    browser.focus();
    // the onCloseEventHandler it notifies that the child has been closed.
    browser.fromSon({ type: "info", payload: { message: "child was closed" } });
    timer = undefined;
    popup = undefined;
  }
}

export const WindowOpener = (props) => {
  useEffect(() => {
    browser.fromSon = (res) => {
      props.bridge(res);
    };
  }, [props]);

  /**
   * opens a child
   */
  const onClickHandler = (evt) => {
    const { url, name, opts } = props;
    // if there is  already a child open, let's set focus on it
    if (popup && !popup.closed) {
      popup.focus();

      return;
    }
    // we open a new window.
    popup = browser.open(url, name, opts);

    setTimeout(() => {
      // The opener object is created once and only if a window has a parent
      browser.fromSon({ type: "info", payload: { message: "child was open" } });
    }, 0);

    if (timer === null) {
      // each two seconds we check if the popup still open or not
      timer = setInterval(watcher, 2000);
    }

    return;
  };

  const { children } = props;

  return (
    <button type="button" onClick={onClickHandler}>
      {children}
    </button>
  );
};
```

now let's create the son

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";

export const Son = () => {
  const [message, setMessage] = useState("");

  /** This Component only renders on a popup window */
  useEffect(() => {
    if (!window.opener) {
      window.location.pathname = "/";
    }
  }, []);

  const onChangeHandler = (evt) => {
    const { value } = evt.target;

    setMessage(value);
    window.opener.fromSon(value);
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <input type="text" value={message} onChange={onChangeHandler} />
    </div>
  );
};
```

the home component

```
import React from "react";
import logo from "./logo.svg";
import { WindowOpener } from "./window-opener";
export class Home extends React.Component {
    constructor (props) {
        super(props);

        this.state = {
            message: ""
        }
        this.sonResponse = this.sonResponse.bind(this);
    }

    sonResponse (err, res) {
        if (err) {
            this.setState({ message: res })
        }
        this.setState({ message: res })
    }

    render () {
        const {message} = this.state;
        return (
            <div>
                <header className="App-header">
                    <img src={logo} className="App-logo" alt="logo" />
                    <p>
                        Edit <code>src/App.js</code> and save to reload.
        </p>
                    <a
                        className="App-link"
                        href="https://reactjs.org"
                        target="_blank"
                        rel="noopener noreferrer"
                    >
                        {message}
        </a>
                    <WindowOpener
                        url="http://localhost:3000/son"
                        bridge={this.sonResponse}
                    >
                        Open Browser
      </WindowOpener>
                </header>

            </div>
        )
    }
}
```